# composer ошибки при установке зависимостей

Tags: ssh, composer

Пытаюсь интегрировать сайт на Drupal 7 с сервисом рассылок mailchimp. Установил модуль для друпала MailChimp

В настройках модуля, вставил api key для mailchimp. И вот тут появились проблемы

1. Для работы модуля нужна библиотека [MailChimp PHP](https://github.com/thinkshout/mailchimp-api-php/releases) скачал и залил ее в папку libraries вроде все норм.
2. в архиве с файлами библиотеки есть файл composer.json

```js
{
  "name": "thinkshout/mailchimp-api-php",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "type": "library",
  "description": "PHP library for v3 of the MailChimp API",
  "keywords": ["mailchimp", "mail"],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/thinkshout/mailchimp-api-php",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.1"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.21"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Mailchimp\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Mailchimp\\Tests\\": "tests/src/"
    }
  }
}
```

сайт лежит на shared хостинге reg ru 
Подключаюсь по SSH перехожу в папку с библиотекой MailChimp выполняю команду php composer.phar install, происходит скачивание и в консоле появляются ошибки прикрепил скрин.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и тут возник вопрос как повысить версию php в консоле с 5.3 до 5.5, погуглил узнал что в консоле одна версия, в панеле управелния хостингом другая. Т.е просто переключение версии в панели  не помогло. 
И как установить расширение для php dom ? попытался сделать через ssh , не хватает прав на выполнение команды. Так понимаю писать только в тп рег ру

И как мне решить проблему с версией php в консоле ? тоже писать в тп?

Благодарю за любую помощь.

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют. 2. да, лучше сначала обсудить эту проблему с техподдержкой. подозреваю, впрочем, что проблема уже обсуждалась, и, возможно, присутствует в «часто задаваемых вопросах» на сайте хостера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ваш хостер имеет несколько версий PHP, то вам просто нужно указать полный путь к нужной версии. Скорее всего полный путь указан либо в панели управления на сайте хостера, либо у него в ЧаВО. Т. е. вам нужно писать не `php composer.phar install`, а что-то вроде `/usr/local/php55/bin/php composer.phar install`.

А вот установить расширение вы вряд ли сможете. Но вообще-то DOM [включено по-умолчанию](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php). Возможно вам нужно просто подключить конфигурационный файл, где это расширение прописано. У моего хостера можно включить в настройках сайта нужные параметры PHP, а потом подключить в консоли конфигурационный файл PHP от этого сайта через параметр -c: `/usr/local/php55/bin/php -c /.../my.site.ini ...`. Вполне возможно что вам тоже просто нужно указать какой-то определённый .ini файл. Если же вдруг по какой-то причине это расширение действительно отсутствует - то обратитесь в ТП хостера, с просьбой его установить.

---

Дополнение:

Кстати вот ссылки с ЧаВО reg.ru по вашим вопросам: [dom](https://hosting.reg.ru/hosting/php?_ga=1.231234847.165303935.1466065405), [выбор версии](https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/hosting-sajtov/yazyki-programmirovaniya-i-skripty/planirovschik-cron) PHP

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Действительно стоило указать путь к нужной мне версии php. Пример моей команды:
/opt/php/5.5/bin/php-cgi  composer.phar install
все нужные зависимости установились и также пропала ошибка связанная с расширением dom